# Force upgrade after fallback to polling?

Tags: socket.io

This may be a stupid question, but i am wondering if there is a way to force socket.io to periodically retry to use websocket as transport instead of polling?

I noticed that sometimes my application cannot establish a websocket connection (Handshake failed: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET). Socket.io correctly falls back to polling then, but it never seems to try to switch back to websockets again, even if it would work. Is my observation correct?
If so, what would you suggest?

Please let me know if you need any code. I couldn't really think of a relevant code example, since this is more like a theoretical question.

Comment: I'd say fix your server to not reject connections.  Or, if you're in polling mode, you can, every once in a while, drop the connection and reconnect from the client and it will automatically try webSocket again.

Comment: Yeah. This was just an example provided to understand the situation. Obviously i don't want to have the handshake fail initially. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: My point was that an occasional ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is likely not just specific to webSocket connections.  It's probably just a sign of bad health of your web server.  If this is your server, your priority should be to make your server healthy so this doesn't happen, not to try to work around it with client code.

Comment: Yes. That is how this question was spawned. Our server was very unstable and thus the initial handshake failed 1 in 10 tries. We are investigating those server issues seperately, but this was not really part of this question/issue. Thanks for the concern anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Socket.io correctly falls back to polling then, but it never seems to try to switch back to websockets again, even if it would work. Is my observation correct?

Yes, correct.

> If so, what would you suggest?

I dont think its a job of a lib to try to reastablish connection. You can set your own listener, that checks server availability - some times servers crash and users wont notice that they dont have connection anymore...

Kinda example of what we have on client side, hope it helps digging.

```
    //If sockets close
    window.ws.onclose = function (e) {

        ws.onclose = null;
        ws.onerror = null;
        ws.onopen = null;
        // restart sockets in: 3000 ms 
        setTimeout(function () { ctx.createWS(); }, 3000); 
    };

    window.ws.onerror = function (error) {
        //On error we will try to restart sockets in function described before
        ws.close();
    };
```

Comment: Alright. Thank you. Just wanted to have confirmation that it would be my job to keep track of that. Will accept as soon as it is possible.